# Decorate all instances returned by structuremap 4 with castle.Dynamicproxy

Tags: .net, aop, structuremap, castle-dynamicproxy

Right now I am decorating my **StructureMap4** mapped types like, `IFormsAuthenticationProvider` with a Castle-generated proxy with  `tryCatchInterceptor` in the StructureMap4 registry. For example:

```
public class AuthenticationRegistry : Registry
{
    public AuthenticationRegistry()
    {
        var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
        var tryCatchInterceptor = new TryCatchInterceptor();

        For<IFormsAuthenticationProvider>().Use<FormsAuthenticationProvider>()
            .DecorateWith(x => proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IFormsAuthenticationProvider>(x, tryCatchInterceptor));
    }
}

public class TryCatchInterceptor : IInterceptor
{..}
```

But as you can see, I have to specify the type in the decoration method. so, will have to define similar decorators for all IType->Type, at which point the code becomes repetitive.

Question: is there a way to do this at a common place, for all types without repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much R&D, I don't think there is an existing mechanism to do it in the structuremap4.0 version.

however, I came up with a dynamic solution of my own.

created a class template and created the class on the fly. loaded the class into memory after compiling and ran the code.

**classTemplate.txt**

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using StructureMap;
using System.Web;
using Company1.WebApplication.App1.Meta;
using Company1.WebApplication.App1.Meta.Interceptors;

namespace Company1.WebApplication.App1
{
    public class DynamicUtils 
    {
        private static StructureMapDependencyResolver _structureMapResolver { get; set; }
        private static ProxyGenerator _ProxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();

        public static void ConfigureCastleInterceptor(Container container)
        {
            container.Configure(x =>
                {
                    ##INTERFACE##
                });
        }
    }
}
```

and in my **Global.asax**, wrote code for loading it

```
    private static void ConfigureCastleInterceptor(Container container)
            {
                string classBody = File.ReadAllText(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/RuntimeClasses/RegisterInterceptors.txt");
                var classBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                string interfaceTemplate = "x.For<##INTERFACE##>()
.DecorateAllWith(y => _ProxyGenerator
.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<##INTERFACE##>(y, new TryCatchLoggingInterceptor())); \n";

                foreach (var instance in container.Model.AllInstances)
                {
                    if (instance.PluginType.FullName.Contains("Company1.WebApplication"))
                        classBuilder.Append(interfaceTemplate.Replace("##INTERFACE##", instance.PluginType.FullName));
                }
                classBody = classBody.Replace("##INTERFACE##", classBuilder.ToString());


                var csharp = new CSharpCodeProvider();
                var compiler = new CompilerParameters();
                foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                {
                    compiler.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(asm.Location);
                }
                compiler.GenerateInMemory = true;
                compiler.GenerateExecutable = false;

                CompilerResults results = csharp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compiler, classBody);

                if (!results.Errors.HasErrors)
                {
                    Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
                    Type program = assembly.GetType("Company1.WebApplication.App1.DynamicUtils");
                    MethodInfo configureCastleInterceptor = program.GetMethod("ConfigureCastleInterceptor");

                    configureCastleInterceptor.Invoke(null, new Object[] { container });
                }

                else 
                {
                    throw new Exception(results.Errors.ToString());
                }
            }
```